# Why is $V$ isomorphic to $F[x]/(b(x))$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$, and let  $T\colon V\to V$ be a linear transformation. Consider $V$ as an $F[x]$-module where the action of $x$ on $V$ is defined as the action of $T$ on $V$.  Let $f(x)\in F[x]$ and suppose there is a basis $B$ of $V$ such that the matrix of $T$ with respect to $B$ is the companion matrix of $f(x)$. Why does it follow that $V$ is isomorphic to $F[x]/(f(x))$? I can see that $V$ is a cyclic $F[x]$-module with generator the first element of $B$, but I'm not sure how to finish the argument.

Comment: Tried isomorphism theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is an $R$-module that is generated by an element $m$ then the map $\varphi \colon R \rightarrow M$ defined by $\varphi(r) = rm$ defines an epimorphism and so $M \cong R / \ker(\varphi) = R / \mathrm{Ann}(m)$. In your case, if $\mathcal{B} = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is the basis under which $T$ is represented as a companion matrix of the polynomial $f(x)$, then by letting $\varphi \colon \mathbb{F}[x] \rightarrow M$ act as $\varphi(p(x)) = p(x)v_1 = (p(T))v_1$, we have $V \cong \mathbb{F}[x] / \mathrm{Ann}(v_1)$.

It remains to show that $\mathrm{Ann}(v_1) = (f(x))$. If $p(x) \in \mathrm{Ann}(v_1)$, then because $v_1$ is a generator, we have $p(x) \in \mathrm{Ann}(V)$, or in other words, $p(T) = 0$. Since the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $f(x)$, we have $\mathrm{Ann}(v_1) = (f(x))$.

Comment: Could you remind me how one shows that $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$? I know it is true, but can't recall the proof.

Comment: By definition, you calculate that $f(T)v_1 = 0$ which shows $f(T)v_i = f(T)T^{i-1}v_1 = T^{i-1}f(T)v_1 = 0$ and so $f(T) = 0$. This means that the minimal polynomial $m_T(x)$ divides $f(x)$. However, if $\deg m_T < n$ then $(m_T)(T)(v_1) = 0$ gives a non-trivial linear relation between $v_1, Tv_1 = v_2, \ldots, T^{n-1}v_1 = v_n$ which is impossible since $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is a basis.

Comment: Great, that is perfect, thanks.